# Get TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'

Tags: python, typeerror

```
def get_n_Antiprotozoal_for_PCT(self, pct,n):
    """Return all the data for a given PCT."""
    return int(db.session.query(func.sum(PrescribingData.items).filter(PrescribingData.BNF_code.startswith('0504'),PrescribingData.PCT == pct)).limit(n).first()[0])
```

Here is my code and when I pick the pct like "01A", it is good. But when I pick the pct like "123" or "ABC",I get an error: TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'.

I think the problem is about "PrescribingData.PCT == pct", but I don't know how to define pct.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need to debug your query, it returns `None`. Start from the bare minimum and rebuild the query piece by piece to see where it goes wrong and/or if there are any items meeting the conditions in your query.

Comment: The error is telling you that your `db.session.query` returns `None` and therefore can't be converted to an `int`.

Comment: break out the call into separate parts so you can get at their results (such as your suspect `filter()`), then you can use `print()` to show what each result is, or call your program with [PDB](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) `python -m pdb myscript.py` .. this will allow to you to set breakpoints `b`, continue `c` to them and inspect the state at different points (`?` for help and commands)